# Entity Framework Code First Updating Record is Not Saving Parent

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, entity-framework, dbcontext

My code below saves the record fine but it does not save the client. I get no errors it saves the record to DB but does not create relationship with parent client. Whilst debugging i have stepped through an made sure that var client actually contains a client object.

Any help is very much appreciated!

Anyway here is my code:

```
using (var context = new TDBContext())
        {
            if (SelectedProject != null)
            {
                var client = (from x in context.Clients
                              where x.ID == (Guid) comboClient.SelectedValue
                              select x).FirstOrDefault();

                Project project = new Project()
                {
                    ID = (Guid) SelectedProject,
                    ProjectCode = textProjectCode.Text,
                    Client = client,
                    ProjectStart = dateProjectStart.SelectedDate,
                    Active = checkActive.IsChecked
                };

                context.Projects.Attach(project);    
                context.Entry(project).State = EntityState.Modified;
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Project ID not loaded!", "Error!", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
            }
        }
```

The project entity:

```
public Project()
    {

    }

    [Key]
    public Guid ID { get; set; }      
    public string ProjectCode { get; set; }
    public Client Client { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ProjectStart { get; set; }
    public bool? Active { get; set; }
```

The client entity:

```
public Client()
    {

    }
    [Key]
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public string ClientName { get; set; }
    public byte[] ClientLogo { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Project> Projects { get; set; }
```

Comment: Kind of a funky way of doing it (I would fetch the client and update its child collection), but it would probably work if you also set the entity state of Project.Client to modified as well. Also, I prefer `First()` to `FirstOrDefault()` when I am counting on the existence of the parent record. I would at least make sure it's not null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit (finally got it working):

I created a separate method to update the client. I call this from my main save method. This works every time now. I'm sure that I can do this better (i.e. all in the same method):

```
private void SaveClient()
    {
        using (var context = new PDBContext())
        {
            var client = (from x in context.Clients
                          where x.ID == (Guid) comboClient.SelectedValue
                          select x).FirstOrDefault();

            var project = (from x in context.Projects
                           where x.ID == SelectedProject
                           select x).FirstOrDefault();

            project.Client = client;

            context.Projects.Attach(project);

            context.Entry(project).State = EntityState.Modified;

            context.SaveChanges();
        }

        PopulateClientCombo();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to assign the ClientId column not just the Client reference.  EF is smart enough to check when the ClientId exists and has a different id than the client navigation property, but if the id is blank, it'll ignore that Client navigation property altogether.

*Edit*

Ah, then call context.Projects.Add(project) instead of changing it to Modified.

Comment: Tried Client.ID = client.ID but it does not work. I get "Invalid initializer member declarator". What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: the client id property on the project entity itself.  i.e.  project.ClientId = client.Id.

Comment: I do not have a Client ID property I have a Client which is parent entity of Project. They are in a 1-n relationship.

Comment: I edited for clarity i realize initial description may have been confusing.

Comment: Hmm. But calling context.Projects.Add(project) instead of changing it to Modified just results in a PK violation. I'm not trying to add a new record.

Comment: Needed to add client state modified

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so sure about your use of EF but I'll try to give a shot for this problem. Please note that this is quite a different approach from yours. In short, I will create/get Client's Id and add it into the new Project object which is being added.

1. Add one more property to your Project entity: `public Guid ClientId { get; set; }`. This stands alongside with `public Client Client { get; set; }`. When you apply migrations, your Project table now has ClientId to refers the Client (1-to-many relationship, isn't it?)
2. Apply migrations and make sure the tables themselves have the references.
3. In your method, adding ClientId when you create new Projects. This should be enough.

   ```
   Project project = new Project()
   {
       ID = (Guid) SelectedProject,
       ProjectCode = textProjectCode.Text,
       ClientId = (Guid)comboClient.SelectedValue, // Your client's Guid. Make sure this record exists in the database.
       ProjectStart = dateProjectStart.SelectedDate,
       Active = checkActive.IsChecked
   };
   ```

This is what I usually do with my projects. When you **query**, you load the data and EntityFramework has methods to do that for you. See also: [Loading Related Data](https://ef.readthedocs.io/en/staging/querying/related-data.html)